# Excel formula, COUNTIF two conditions

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I need a formula in Excel or VBA function, which will allow me to count the answers aggregated according to previously question. Table below will help me to explain this:

```
+-----------+-------------+
|     A     |      B      |
+-----------+-------------+
| Question1 | Question2   |
| d         | a,b,c,d     |
| a         | a,b,c,d,e,f |
| a         | a,b         |
| b         | a,e         |
| c         | b,e,h,k     |
| d         | b,f         |
| d         | b,g,j       |
| b         | c,d,e       |
| a         | a,c,j       |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Question1 column will be treated as profilling question, for example company size. a - small, b - medium, c - big, d - enterprise. I need on my output to count question2 answers aggregated to company size. For example, how many small companies have ticked answer a etc. I know how to count overall percentage of each question in answers, but I need compare it to profiling Question1. I do not know how to combine COUNTIF function which addotional condition - IF column A contains "a" pass it to COUNTIF(). I am considering VBA solution too.

Kind Regards

Comment: Try `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: The problem is that I can COUNTIF() on one condition, I can run this formula on Question2 column, but It will give me results how many times each anwers were answered. For example: answer A, answered 5 times, Answer B 6 times. But I need to compare It to column Question1, for example how many times answer A was answered by "a" from Question1. A little bit confusing.

Comment: *Very* confusing actually; enough so that your question is *unclear*. One problem is that your "Question2" column contains many values; looks like "Question2" is actually "Question2+Question3+Question4+Question5+Question6" - you need to normalize the data to query it efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is confusing, I am not sure if I understood it correctly, but this is how you can count the numbers using **`COUNTIFS`** formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D3,$B:$B,"*"&E$2&"*")
```

Place this formula in cell E3 and drag it across the rows and columns for Q1 and Q2.
Assuming your data is placed like this:

[image]